# how to allow two passwords

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/16/ and try to set two possible passwords like:

```js
$("#b").click(function() {
  var password = "password";
  var password2 = "mouse";
  var dog = $("#pass").val();
  var mouse = $("#pass").val();
  if (dog !== password || mouse !== password2) {
    $("#err").text("Incorrect password");
  } else {
    $("#err").text("Password correct! Do whatever you need to do here.");
  }
});
```

but it doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Comment: Your dog variable reference to the same $("pass")-object then the mouse variable

Comment: Your code says your password is invalid if it is not equal to "password" or not equal to "mouse", therefore valid if it equals "password" AND "mouse", both at the same time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/118/

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenters mentioned under your post, your solution has a couple flaws. I re-wrote this for you. Just add the passwords you want into an array.

```
$("#b").click(function() {
    var passwords = ["password", "dog"];  // All the passwords you want to accept.

    if(passwords.indexOf($("#pass").val()) === -1) {
        $("#err").text("Incorrect password");
    }
    else {
        $("#err").text("Password correct! Do whatever you need to do here.");   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/113/
If this is the answer you want, press the green tick on the left.

Comment: Agreed, array is the way to go. You don't want to enumerate every single possibility by hand. `indexOf` is a way smarter solution.

Comment: @JeremyThille, exactly what I was thinking. It's not like there will be 1 million passwords they want to accept either, so performance isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Ken Y-N, issue is OR condition.

```
if (dog !== password || mouse !== password2)
```

even if `mouse` has valid value, it will not be checked since, `dog` is not equal to `password`.

You can try something like this:

```
if(!(dog === password || mouse === password2)){ ... }
```

Also dog and mouse will hold same value. So its better to have 1 variable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/LpdQm/114/)